# Time Complexity of multiple nested loops

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, nested-for-loop

What would be the complexity of the below code :
Since the increment is not by 1 and the conditions are not direct, how to calculate the complexity ?

```
for(int h =0; h<n;h+=2)
    {
       for (int j =1; j<=n*n; j*=3)
       {
          for (int k =2; k+k <=n;++k)
          { 
          } 
       } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 nested loops. Let's analyze each of them (keep in mind that we don't care about any constants, no matter how large they are):

`for(int h=0; h<n; h+=2)` - O(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>N) -> `O(N)`

`for (int j=1; j<=n*n; j*=3)` - O(log<sub>3</sub>N<sup>2</sup>) -> `O(logN2)`

`for (int k=2; k+k<=n; ++k)`- O(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>N) -> `O(N)`

Since all the loops are nested O(N * logN<sup>2</sup> * N) -> `O(N2*logN2)`

Answer (score 0):

1st loop: n times, constant jump (+2). hence `n/2` times which is `O(n)`

2nd loop: n^2 times, geometric jumps (*3) hence `\log_{3}{n^2} = O(\log{n})`

3rd loop: n/2 times, which is also `n/2` times

loops are nested so you got `O\(n*log{n}*\)=O\(n^{2}log{n}\)`

Comment: Thanks! Also a follow up question : If the 2nd loop and 3rd loop do not have any statements and just have a semicolon after loop, then how do we calculate the complexity ? Example :for(int h =0; h<n;h+=2)

{

for (int j =1; j<=n*n; j*=3)

;

for (int k =2; k+k <=n;++k)

;

}

Comment: If I understood correctly what you wrote then you should sum the second and the third loops. (the thumb rule: nested are multiplied and disjoints are summed